# URL working on localhost but not in production

Tags: django, django-templates

I have build a website using django and uplaoded it but url redirection within the website is not working.
It gives 404 error. The home page is loading fine but other links are not working.
It works perfectly fine on local machine.
Please help as unable to figure out the reason

base.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>                      
<li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('services/',views.services,name="services"),
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'tipster_app/index.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'tipster_app/contact.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request,'tipster_app/about.html')

def services(request):
    return render(request,'tipster_app/services.html')
```

about.html

```
{% block content%}
        <p>Content</p>
{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: How does the link look like? Share the *rendered link* as well as the template where you render this.

Comment: Added the required information

Comment: Please check what is giving you 404 on prod specifically: Django or Nginx?

Comment: Are your templates within Project-->App-->Templates-->AppTemplates-->index.html hierarchy?

Comment: It is using Apache. How can i check this?

Comment: Yes.. It is the hierarchy

Comment: Take a look at logs. And add apache config to the question.

Comment: [ N 2021-03-01 09:46:50.4274 1054143/Tf age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1117 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 1070810, application /home/h86xqg1zxngx/tipster_project (production)... This is what i see in logs..Please help