# I get error 404 on all URLs (when I click on a menu item on home page) in production. Everything works on localhost. What am I missing please?

Tags: django, deployment, django-templates, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have deployed a django app on a shared hosting server using cpanel. The home page loads fine (I see only 1 error - 404 on favicon on developer's console). All the pictures and styling are showing as expected on the home page.  I have placed my images on a google cloud bucket and I am referencing CSS/js from CDNs. My problem is that when I click on menu items, none of the the URLs are working.
'File not found' is displayed.  On the dev console/Network I see error 404. There are no errors in the logfile.

This exact question was asked previously but there was no resolution as far as I can tell:
[URL working on localhost but not in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406758/url-working-on-localhost-but-not-in-production)

I have tried so many things including:
Setting DEBUG=True in settings, TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True,
specifying default django template loaders one by one then together in TEMPLATES.

I have made sure that all my apps are listed in INSTALLED_APPS.

I even ran collectstatic and tried pointing DIRS to this static folder.

After every change I restart the Python App in Cpanel and clear the browser cache

Initially I had installed whitenoise to serve static files but I commented it out in settings when I went the CDN route because I was getting 404s.

Initially my templates were at project level (project\templates, project\templates\app).
I later duplicated them at application level (application\templates\application*.html).
And collectstatic made more copies at STATIC_ROOT.

Here are some code snippets:

## base.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a></li>

<li><a href="{% url 'programme:research' %}">Research</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'programme:training' %}">Training</a></li>
```

## urls.py (ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls')

```
    app_name = 'myproject'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
        path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
        path('programme/', include('programme.urls')),
    ]
```

## urls.py (programme)

```
    app_name = 'programme'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('research', ResearchView.as_view(), name='research'),
        path('training', TrainingView.as_view(), name='training'),
    ]
```

## views.py (people)

```
    class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):
        template_name = "home.html"

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ...
            return context

    class AboutView(generic.TemplateView):
        template_name = "about.html"
```

## views.py (programme)

```
    class ResearchView(generic.TemplateView):
        template_name = "programme/research.html"

    class TrainingView(generic.TemplateView):
        template_name = "programme/training.html
```

## settings.py

```
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'people',
        'programme',
    ]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            # findMyWay("templates"),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',                
            ],
        },        
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: With "DEBUG=True", have you more information on the 404 error ?

Comment: There is no more information even with "DEBUG=True".  Only "File not found" is displayed on the browser. "404 Not found" is the response status when I right-click and "Inspect" under the "Network" tab.  There is also no error in the passenger.log file  on the server.

Comment: And do you have some useful information from Apache log ?

Comment: Error: The system failed to open the file “/etc/apache2/logs/error_log” for reading because of an error: Permission denied.   I have sent this to the hosting provider and await their response.  Thank you.

Comment: Apparently we don't have access to the apache error log on a shared hosting so they sent me a text file @PhilippeSisowath . It has the error 'AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: https://mydomain/'. Does this mean a server config error?

Comment: It may be an Apache configuration error. Do you share the Apache configuration? And by the way, have you set custom Django logger to trace the error and/or Django debug toolbar?

Comment: Yes @PhilippeSisowath it's a shared hosting service and the provider is busy investigating the error.  I'll update you.  Thank you very much for bringing django logger to my attention.  I found a gist at https://gist.github.com/darthwade/d916711bb54661ce5ab8 that I'll use for the config.

Comment: Feedback from the hosting provider is that they have fixed the file/folder permissions on the serve and performed all possible troubleshoots from their end.  The problem persists.  I cannot even load https://mysite/admin